# AST unquoting using quasiquotes and tree returned from reify

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10, scala-quasiquotes

I was trying to use Toolbox and quasiquote together to do code generation tasks, and faced with StackOverflowError while using AST of object returned from `reify(x).tree`, my code is as follows:

```
abstract class A[T] {def i: T}
class B(val i: Int) extends A[Int]
object A {

    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
    import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
    import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

    val javaSeparator = "$"
    val curId = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger()

    protected def freshName(prefix: String): TermName = {
        newTermName(s"$prefix$javaSeparator${curId.getAndIncrement}")
 }

 def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val b = new B(2)
    calculate(b)
 }

 def calculate(a: A[_]): Unit = {

    val toolBox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
    val i = freshName("i")
    val aTree = reify(a).tree

    val tree = q"""
       val $i = $aTree.i
      println($i)
   """

   toolBox.eval(tree)
  }
}
```

when I remove type parameter of class A or use `def calculate(a: B)`, the `toolBox.eval` success and work as expected, i.e. print 2 in console.

I don't quite understand why this happens, can someone explain why class definition with type parameters fails the evaluation?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Though first I'd like to ask what you wanted to achieve by doing `reify(a).tree`. What is the result that you're expecting?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako, the code above was just to show the failure I faced with. In my real project, since A has many subclasses with different Array type, I want to manipulate them all in calculate, at the same time, avoid the boxing and unboxing overhead due to polynomial. reify(a).tree was just to use parameter in AST I can consider. Are there better ways to use argument directly in AST? Thank you.

Comment: So, when you write `reify(a).tree`, you want to get `Ident(TermName("a"))`, which retains a link to the runtime value of the argument `a` passed to the current invocation of the method, right?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako, yes, "link to the runtime value of the argument a" is what I want, you mean manual tree construction with Ident(TermName("a")) is just ok and a preferred method? Is it hygiene by doing so?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako, I tried substitute `val aTree = reify(a).tree ` by `val aTree = Ident(newTermName("a"))`, but a "not found: value a" error

Comment: @EugeneBurmako, by the way, is there a way to check the bytecode generated by compiler during `toolBox.eval`? Currently, I can only debug the `compile` method in `ToolBoxImpl`, using the className there and getBytes using ClassLoader.

Comment: No, just Ident(TermName("a")) won't be enough, because manual tree construction isn't hygienic. Some magic sauce is needed, which is provided by reify :)

Comment: To see the bytecodes, try this: https://github.com/xeno-by/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/ScalaSettings.scala#L195

Comment: Anyway, it looks like you're blocked by a bug, and I'll try to take a look at in the near future.

Comment: Okay, found a workaround. Please check the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8833. Until the bug is fixed, you can use a workaround outlined in the comments in JIRA. I've only provided a workaround for 2.11.x, and if you need one for 2.10.x, please leave a comment.

Comment: I will, in 1-2 hours. Need to go now.

Comment: Done. Updated the comment in JIRA.

Comment: Thx for the updates. By the way, it seems .class files dumped by `Ydump-classes` does not include `__wrapper$xxxx` that are generated by toolbox compiler? I can find batch of `treecreator`s only

Comment: It does work for me: https://gist.github.com/xeno-by/d632787c4626b1b7db23. What version of Scala are you using?

Comment: I put `-Ydump-classes` option into build.sbt scalacOptions, no wonder I cannot find the generated classes' bytecode :( . I follow your gist above and it works, thank you very much.